# Solve the following multiple integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

Let
$I = \int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{2} \frac{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 - x_4}{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4} dx_1 dx_2 dx_3 dx_4 $
Then $I$ equals

$ (a)\ \frac{1}{2} \\
  (b)\ \frac{1}{3} \\
  (c)\ \frac{1}{4} \\
  (d)\ 1 $

I've tried to solve this and I also could do the whole integration down to the last variable but the process is tremendously lengthy and I have a term $log7$ remaining in my solution. I don't know where I've made a calculative mistake but I just want some hint to solve this problem in a easier and a compact way.

Also I've thought about change of variable transformations but couldn't think of any suitable one.

Comment: By the way, the ans is given to be $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: If you use Approach0, you can easily find that there are existing duplicates of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By symmetry we can see that  $$\int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{2} \frac{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 - x_4}{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4} dx_1 dx_2 dx_3 dx_4= \int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{2} \frac{x_1 + x_2 - x_3 +x_4}{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4} dx_1 dx_2 dx_3 dx_4= \int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{2} \frac{x_1 -x_2 + x_3 +x_4}{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4} dx_1 dx_2 dx_3 dx_4= \int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{2} \frac{-x_1 + x_2 + x_3 +x_4}{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4} dx_1 dx_2 dx_3 dx_4$$
So $$I=\frac 14  \int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{2} \frac{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 - x_4}{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4} + \frac{x_1 + x_2 - x_3 +x_4}{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4} + \frac{x_1 -x_2 + x_3 +x_4}{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4} \frac{-x_1 + x_2 + x_3 +x_4}{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4} dx_1 dx_2 dx_3 dx_4= \frac 14  \int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{2} 2 dx_1 dx_2 dx_3 dx_4=\frac 12.$$